# Adobe Reader XI automaticly save as itself

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, editing

Is it possible to make my Adobe Reader XI overwrite it's own file when I click SAVE, instead of acting like I've clicked Save As.. and ask me about file name and all that nonsense?

Preferably I should click SAVE after making my edits, and that would be it. No more dialogs.

Comment: Are you opening the .pdf in your web browser, or in the Adobe desktop app?

Comment: Adobe needs to hire a user experience expert to work on Adobe Reader, their UX design is very frustrating, even infuriating. This is just one example.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Edit->Preferences (Ctrl+K)
Navigate to "Security (Enhanced)" and uncheck "Enable Protected Mode at startup".
That should do the trick :)

Comment: Note that you have to exit the program for these changes to take effect.

Comment: It works, but isn't disabling safety creating security problems? We are literally disabling protection.

Comment: Same worked for Adobe Reader DC as well! (+1)